# Error in script for estimating $\pi$

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab, and am trying to write a script for this equation for n=100:

[image]

And am using this:

```
n = 100; % set number of terms
sum = 1; % starting point of the sum
sign = 1; % an integer +/- 1
for k = 1 : n % forloop - loops k from 1 to n
    term = sign/(k^2); % compute the term
    sum = sum + term; % update the rolling sum
    sign = - sign; % flip the sign
end;
disp(n); % print n
disp((12*sum)^(0.5)); % print the approximation to pi
disp((12*sum)^(0.5)-pi); % print the error
```

But this is returning some strange values:

```
100 - fine

    4.6764 ????

    1.5348 ????
```

Would anyone be able to point out the mistake I made? I have a feeling it might be the way I raised the sum to the power of 0.5, but am not entirely sure.

Thanks

Comment: This is your error: initialize with sum = 0.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMontgomery-Smith, this was indeed the error. I am curious though, since the sum begins from $k=1$ why do we set the sum from starting at $0$ ?

Comment: Write a simple program to compute $\sum_{k=1}^3 k$.  Then go step by step through the program to predict what the computer will do.  Then it should become clear to you.

Comment: You should read [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  It leads you through some steps stolen from debugging larger programs because they work.  There is a tendency to ignore good practice on small programs because they are small and "the overhead isn't worth it".  That is fine when it works.  If it doesn't-do the careful stuff to make it work.

Comment: Thanks guys, you have equipped me well for my journey to introductory matrix laboratory! :D

Helping those in need makes you larger than life.

Comment: Alright, got it. the $\text{sum} \space = 0$ term is not related to the index $k$ at all. It is just the starting value for the sum!